# After switching from a filesystem to mongodb approach, how can I recreate nested directory iteration?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I was storing files in a nested file structure like

data/category/year/month/day/type/subtype/0.json

and to get a list of files / directories within any folder I'd simply use a func like:

```
  getDirectoryContentsSync(pathName) {
    let exists = this.exists(pathName);
    if (exists) {
      let files = fs.readdirSync(pathName)
      return files;
    } else {
      return [];
    }
  }
```

Now I'm switching to storing files in mongodb, identifying the files by their original file-path string like:

```
  store(data, path) {
    this.db.collection('fs').insertOne({
      path,
      data
    });
  }
  load(path) {
      let data = this.db.collection('fs').find({
        path
      })[0].data;
      return data;
  }
```

But I'm struggling to figure out a way to continue iterating through the structure the way I used to. The approach I'm thinking is pretty gross, like to assign a separate value for each sub-path pointing to children but I think its gonna be a really bad approach, something like:

```
  store(data, path) {
    this.db.collection('fs').insertOne({
      path,
      data
    });
    let pathParts = path.split("/");
    let subPath = "";
    pathParts.forEach(dir => {
      subPath += dir;
      this.db.collection('dir').insertOne({
        path: subPath,
        data: true,
        children: []
      });
    });
  }
```

That's not the full code for the concept because I realized it seemed like an overly complicated way to do it and decided to stop and ask. I'm just new to mongo db and I bet there's a much better way to handle this but have no idea where to start. What's a good way to do what I want?

Comment: Have you tried using a regular expression, like `db.collection.find({path:{$regex:"^data/category/year/month/day/type/"}})`

Comment: @Joe the issue is when my goal is simply to retrieve a list of data/category/ years, a function like `.find({path: {$regex: "(data/category/)(.+)" }})` will return actual gigabytes of data when all I want is a list of strings for the years within `category`, like "2001", "2002", "2003", etc

Comment: Oh, if you only want a segment of the path, you could use aggregation to split the string and group

Comment: @Joe I figured it out with help from regex (didnt know about that feature yet), but by assigning paths to a separate collection